# Create a Complex 3D Shape in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, shapes

I am trying to create a complex 3D shape in Adobe Photoshop, like the shape pictured below. Is this possible? Are there any tutorials available? I was unable to find any. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the 3d tools in Photoshop are meant for that.. its more for "simple" stuff.. for complex stuff I recommend Maya or 3DS Max

Comment: Exactly. The only way to create something like this in Photoshop would be to actually paint/draw it.

Comment: There is a meta for a CG Artists stack exchange that will answer questions exactly like this one. It needs more followers. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38889/cg-artists?referrer=HhJgXPk4zFcAw7hjn5MhOA2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the answer official ...

**Photoshop is not the tool you want to use for this.** A dedicated 3D app will make your life much less painful. As pointed out in the comment, you would essentially have to do this by hand.

[The Blender/3D SE Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender) has been committed and a beta should pop up soon. Put your name on the list and ask more there.